# TCP IP Connection issues with linux server and VB client

Tags: linux

I am trying to develop a server program on linux (on embedded target) and a client in my host PC using VB6.  My client program just reads single byte of data and then nothing happens, it does not take off. No communication happens between client and server thereafter. What could be the problem?
Given below is the code for client and server

VB-Client Side Code

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()
    Form1.WindowState = 2
    Form1.Visible = True
    If Winsock1 <> closed Then
    Winsock1.Close  ' closing the winsock if already open
    End If
    Winsock1.RemoteHost = "192.168.1.100"
    Winsock1.RemotePort = 3000 'setting this machine as a Client
    Winsock1.Connect
    End Sub

   'Data capture events
    Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    For i = 0 To 30
    Winsock1.GetData RECVDI(i), vbByte, 30
    If (RECVDI(i) - 48) = 1 Then
    Shape1(i).FillColor = &HFF00&
    Else
    Shape1(i).FillColor = &HFFFFFF
    End If
    Next i
    End Sub

A separate command button to connect in case of loss of connection
Private Sub Command11_Click()


 If Winsock1 <> closed Then
    Winsock1.Close  ' closing the winsock if already open
    End If
    Winsock1.RemoteHost = "192.168.1.100"
    Winsock1.RemotePort = 3000 'setting this machine as a Client
    Winsock1.Connect
    End Sub


Server Side Code
int main()
{ 
Int i;
char DATA[32];
sys_init(); - opens the file
for (i=0;i<31;i++)
{
 sleep(1);
 DATA[i]=i;
 Eth_Send(3000,&DATA[0],31);
}
sys_close();
}

Code for Eth_Send()

unsigned char Eth_Send(unsigned int port_no, unsigned char *ptr,   unsigned int nbytes)
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    int j;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    char val[15];
    char sendBuff[1025];
    char send[31];

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port_no); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 10); 

    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 
    for(j=0;j<nbytes;j++)
    {
      send[j]=*ptr;
      ptr++;
    }

    for (j=0;j<nbytes;j++)
    {
      snprintf(val+j,sizeof (val),"%d",send[j]);
    }
    snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%s",val);
    write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 
    close(connfd);
    sleep(1);

return 0;   

}
```

Comment: did you try telnet to the server see if the ports are even open ? 
telnet 192.168.1.100 3000

Comment: When I put eth_send at end of for loop it works. Kindly explain why does it not work within for loop?